# Windows Phone 8.1 ListView item visibility depending on some condition

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm developing Windows Phone 8.1 application using C#/XAML. The main view of the application contains `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView` class populated with items (the result of some search query).

When users taps an item an additional information pane (**ExtendedInfoPanel**) for that item should appear, but only for **this** item (i.e. only *one item* at a time should expose that additional information).

I played with customizing of `<VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">` by editing a copy of default `ItemContainerStyle` but without success.
Here is my code (only relevant parts):

```xml
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ExtendedInfoPanel">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</Style>
```

```
<ListView
    x:Name="myList"
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    IsItemClickEnabled="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource mySongDataTemplate}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}">
</ListView>
```

Running the snippet above ends in `Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` exception being thrown in application with message:

> Cannot resolve TargetName ExtendedInfoPanel.

Could anybody give me some hints how can I achieve needed behavior?

Comment: Is it possible that the "ExtendedInfoPanel" element is inside a data template?? If so then you cannot refer to it by name like that

Comment: Yes, it is inside DataTemplate element. If so - what are my other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have named elements in a datatemplate you cannot access them by name outside of that data template. The reason for this and a method to access that element is explained [here](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html) by Jerry Nixon.

In short you can navigate the visual tree and find your ExtendedInfoPanel element and change it's visibility. However, in your question you say that you only want one item to display it's details. That means that you should search the visual tree for all other ExtendedInfoPanel elements and hide them. That doesn't sound very effective.

My approach would be more mvvm like. In your model, provide a boolean IsVisible property for the class that will be associated with ExtendedInfoPanel and bind that to the visibility of the element.

Then on the tap event of the list cast the datacontext of the tapped item as your model class and change the IsVisible property for the tapped element and for all the other elements in your collection. 
Tip: You will need an ObservableCollection so that the changes are propagated to the UI. Alternatively you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: In fact, after spending almost 2 days with the issue I`ve implemented it in a similar way. I just wondered whether there were some other approaches to the problem.
Thank you for your answer.